# R - If statement function to set value of new column

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have 2 columns `pos` and `neg`, each with a integer value.

I would like to create a new column `score`, with each element of this column given a value of:

- 1 if pos > neg
- 0 if pos = neg
- -1 if pos < neg

What would be the best way to do this? I am new to creating functions in R, so any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` as `ifelse` is vectorized

```
df1$score <- with(df1, ifelse(pos > neg, 1, ifelse(pos < neg, -1, 0)))
```

---

Or get the difference of 'pos' and 'neg' and apply `sign` which will give values -1, 0, 1 when the sign is negative, value 0 or positive

```
df1$score <- with(df1, sign(pos - neg ))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(pos = c(5, 4, 3, 1, 2), neg = c(5, 3, 4, 1, 3))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Seems like I over-complicated it in my head. Thank you (: